# Send signal to abstract table model outside class

Tags: python, qt, signals, data-modeling, pyqt5

I'm using Python3 + PyQt to display an SQLite3 database. I want to add items to a QAbstractDataModel by hitting a button that gives me a form inside a new window. From what I understand, this means I'll have to either pass a signal (rowsInserted or dataChanged) to the existing data model class, or execute a method inside the class that will emit the signal for me. I want to know what the proper method of doing this is.

I've tried both methods, neither of which worked, and I thought it all felt a little too "hack-ish", like I'm using a great tool the wrong way. Does anybody know how to pass a signal from a dialogue box to an abstract data model using QT5?

BTW, if you're not familiar with PyQt but you know how to do it in C++, let me know! By now I am getting comfortable translating.[image]

Here's a few snippets of what I'm trying:

In my submitItem class:

```
renderData.append([name, eventType]) #changes the data
nrows=dataModel.rowCount(dataModel) #gives me the new row number
dataModel.dataChanged.emit(nrows) #Doesn't like integer (nrows)
# OR
dataModel.refreshData(nrows) # usually needs more arguments, or a QModelIndex to tell it where to refresh the data--it doesn't like just an integer like nrows.
```

This is in my dataModel class currently modelling the renderData variable:

```
def refreshData(self, index, row):
        self.rowsInserted.emit(index, row, row) #needs another argument
        dataModel.rowsInserted.emit() #
        self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
```

Any help is appreciated, hope the question makes some sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you should modify the model through your implementation of the `my_model.setData()` method. Your implementation of this method should emit the `dataChanged()` signal which requires model indices that bound the data that has changed.

So you need to bite the bullet and create one or more model indices so that you can emit the signal that expect that as an argument (you tried emitting this signal but used an integer which obviously failed).

To create model indices, we visit the c++ [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html): (which are far more useful for Python development that the pyqt docs)

> Custom models need to create model indexes for other components to
>   use. To do this, call createIndex() with suitable row and column
>   numbers for the item, and an identifier for it, either as a pointer or
>   as an integer value. The combination of these values must be unique
>   for each item.

There is also details on that page about the implementation of `setData()` and when/how to emit `dataChanged()` (see both the "detailed description" and the details for the individual methods)

You might also want to check out [`QSqlTableModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html) which might negate the need to implement your own model?

Comment: This makes sense. I created a new method of my class that inherits QtCore.QModelIndex() and accepts the row and new data I want to insert, then adds it from inside the class. You hit it right on the nail--I just needed to utilize an index. Thanks!

Comment: P.S. I looked at some of the table models, and thought about using the QT SQL "drivers" (if that's the right term). However, I wanted to have the flexibility to switch to a CSV database, or something entirely different, without having to change my method of displaying data. I figure it's a little more work, but gives me flexibility later...hopefully.